# How would you convert this code from a for loop to a while loop?

Tags: python

Every time I try converting this to work as a while loop it cycles endlessly, any ideas would be very much appreciated. If I use a for loop it runs perfectly fine, so I would assume that using a while loop and iterating over an index value would achieve the same result.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import time
import fitz
from date_check import locate_date

## Each header is a list containing the header text and the form name ##
headers = ["header1", "Header1"]

## cast to lowercase ##
for header in headers:
    header[0] = header[0].lower()

## One of the following is expected to be on the last page of the form ##
end_texts = ["Signature", "Signed"]
## cast to lowercase ##
for i in range(len(end_texts)):
    end_texts[i] = end_texts[i].lower()


## set variables ##
forms = []
first_page = 0
header = ""

## Scan entire document for headers ##
def scan_document(document):
    document = fitz.open(document)
    first_page = False
    last_page = False
    index = 0
    ## This is the loop in question ##
    for i in range(len(document)):
        page = document[i]
        text = page.get_text("text")
        text = text.lower()
        if first_page == False:
            for header in headers:
                if fuzz.partial_ratio(header[0], text) > 90:
                    first_page = i
                    ## Find the date on the page ##
                    date = locate_date(text)
                    forms.append([date, header[1], first_page])
                    break

        elif  first_page != False and last_page == False:
            for end_text in end_texts:
                if end_text in text:
                    last_page = i
                    forms[index].append(last_page)
                    first_page = False
                    last_page = False
                    index += 1
                    break


    ## Return forms list containing first and last page of each form as well as the header ##
    return(forms)
```

I tried using a while loop and iterating over an index, but the program hangs whenever I use it.

````
## set variables ##
forms = []
first_page = 0
header = ""

## Scan entire document for headers ##
def scan_document(document):
    document = fitz.open(document)
    first_page = False
    last_page = False
    page_num = 0
    index = 0
    
    while page_num <= len(document):
        page = document[page_num]
        text = page.get_text("text")
        text = text.lower()
        if first_page == False:
            for header in headers:
                if fuzz.partial_ratio(header[0], text) > 90:
                    first_page = page_num
                    ## Find the date on the page ##
                    date = locate_date(text)
                    forms.append([date, header[1], first_page])
                    page_num += 1
                    break

        elif  first_page != False and last_page == False:
            for end_text in end_texts:
                if end_text in text:
                    last_page = page_num
                    forms[index].append(last_page)
                    first_page = False
                    last_page = False
                    index += 1
                    page_num += 1
                    break
        else:
            page_num += 1

    ## Return forms list containing first and last page of each form as well as the header ##
    return(forms)```
````

Comment: There are simply certain cases where none of your `page_num += 1` statements are being reached.

Comment: Just increase `page_num` once per loop iteration. Don't put it in any conditional statements. It makes no sense why it's conditional, when it wasn't previously. Just increment it in the last line of the loop.

Comment: Have you debugged your program to check that it reaches the `page_num += 1` line of the first two conditions?

Comment: Once you fix that bug you might be hit with the bug that `document[page_num]` will be an index out of range error when `page_num == len(document)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some cases in which the `page_num += 1` line is not reached, you can increase `page_number` value as first operation after entering in the while, but remember to use `page_number - 1` when you use it.

```
## set variables ##
forms = []
first_page = 0
header = ""


## Scan entire document for headers ##
def scan_document(document):
    document = fitz.open(document)
    first_page = False
    last_page = False
    page_num = 0
    index = 0

    while page_num <= len(document):
        page_num += 1
        page = document[page_num - 1]
        text = page.get_text("text")
        text = text.lower()
        if first_page == False:
            for header in headers:
                if fuzz.partial_ratio(header[0], text) > 90:
                    first_page = page_num - 1
                    ## Find the date on the page ##
                    date = locate_date(text)
                    forms.append([date, header[1], first_page])
                    break

        elif first_page != False and last_page == False:
            for end_text in end_texts:
                if end_text in text:
                    last_page = page_num - 1
                    forms[index].append(last_page)
                    first_page = False
                    last_page = False
                    index += 1
                    break

    ## Return forms list containing first and last page of each form as well as the header ##
    return (forms)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase `page_num` in every iteration as some if statements won't be triggered.